# $E_{\lambda}$ is an eigen space, proving $ 1 \leq \dim (E_{\lambda}) \leq m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ having multiplicity $m$.

We need to show that : $ 1 \leq \dim (E_{\lambda}) \leq m$.

My text proves the above result as follows:

We take ordered basis $ \{v_1 , v_2 , \ldots, v_p\}$ for the subspace $E_{\lambda}$, and extend it to form the basis $\beta = \{v_1 , v_2 , \ldots, v_p ,v_{p+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ for the vector space $V$. We let $A = [T]_{\beta}$.

Now, the next step says: Since $v_i \: (1 \leq i \leq p)$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$, we have: 
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}\lambda I_p&B\\O&C\end{pmatrix}.$$
Can anyone explain how can we write $A$ in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

For $j=1,2,\ldots,p$, we have $T(v_j)=\lambda v_j$. On the other hand,
if we let $T(v_j)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ij}v_i$, then
$A_{ij}=\lambda_j\delta_{ij}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,p$,
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the 
*Kronecker delta function*. So, by the definition of matrix representation, 
the sub-matrix of $A=[T]_\beta$ consisting of its
first $p$ columns is
$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda I_p\\O\end{pmatrix}\in M_{n\times p}(F).$$
Therefore we can write $A$ as the desired form.

Comment: I still don't get this, how $A$ came out to be a $2 \times 2$ matrix ?

Comment: Observe that $A_{ij}$ is actually the $ij$-entry of $A$, so by checking the entries of the first $p$ column of $A$ patiently, you will get it.

Comment: I know which textbook you study. Review chapter 2.2 about the definition of matrix representation.